# Coverity Self-Build can't build a C++17 application

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, static-analysis, coverity

I'm trying to use Coverity Scan with an embedded application written in C++17 (ARM GCC Embedded v7.2). The application itself builds well and error/warning-free; however, the Coverity Scan Self-Build tool (`cov-analysis-linux64-2017.07`, the latest) fails to compile certain C++ files with the following error (abridged):

```
[19888] EXECUTING: /home/pavel/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/as -I . -I src -I src/os_config -I eigen -I senoval -I legilimens -I popcop/c++ -I build/current_build_info -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -meabi=5 -alms=build/lst/ch.lst -o build/obj/ch.o /tmp/ccK73Qaa.s
"/home/pavel/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.2.1/bits/c++17_warning.h", line 32:
          error #35: #error directive: This file requires compiler and library
          support for the ISO C++ 2017 standard. This support must be enabled
          with the -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17 compiler options.
  #error This file requires compiler and library support \
   ^
```

As can be seen, the build tool did not pass the option `-std=c++17` to the assembler. By the way, the application's own build system does not make direct calls to the assembler; the Self-Build tool does it on its own. This is how the Coverity Self-Build process is configured:

```
cov-configure --comptype gcc --compiler arm-none-eabi-gcc --template
make clean
cov-build --dir build/cov-int make -j8
cd build
tar czvf coverity.tgz cov-int
```

How do I configure the Self-Build tool to build C++17 code correctly?

Comment: Did a quick bit of searching and couldn't find an easy answer. Seems this is surprisingly difficult. +1 and good luck.

Comment: Additional try PVS-Studio as alternative tool. Now this analyzer supports embedded - https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0561/

Comment: Hello @AndreyKarpov, I've been reading your posts at habrahabr.ru for a while actually. ;) Does PVS-Studio support C++17 though?

Comment: Hello @PavelKirienko. In general, yes. And if something does not work, then write to us and we will quickly fix it.